# Could update scheduled events while it is in sleeping mode in asyncio?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, coroutine

What I need to do is: after I create an event that sleeps for example about 10 seconds to run the task after the 10 seconds is finished, may someone need to do a new event which will decrease this 10 seconds to 5 seconds instead.

So, is there a way to make the asyncio stick with that approach?

I think that asyncio couldn't do that because once it starts sleeping the coroutine will be idle, however, I believe that if I managed to take a coroutine and make customization of it by adding a new feature to it at some point such as adding a listener to its instance and whenever the event launched I can update that coroutine, but actually I can't start updating because I can't define where can I update after inheriting the coroutine? what is the method that I could update or manipulate with it?

Comment: I do not know if `asyncio` can do the trick. Probably you can cancel task, then create a new one, which have another `asyncio.sleep` time interval inside.